# Как продолжить анимация после пробуждения приложения?

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую этот код для создания вращающейся анимации в своем приложении:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)

    animationStatus(true)
}

func animationStatus(_ enable: Bool) {
        if enable {
            if vinylStatus == "true" {
                resumeLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
            } else {
                rotateImageView()
                resumeLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
            }
        } else {
            pauseLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
        }
    }
    
    func rotateImageView() {
        vinylStatus = "true"
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.vinylView.transform = self.vinylView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.rotateImageView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
        layer.speed = 1.0
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        layer.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
```

Но я хочу продолжить анимацию после того, как приложение было скрыто и повторно развернуто, и я использую этот код, но анимация останавливается и не работает. Как исправить эту проблему?

```
@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
            print ("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }
    
@objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
            //pauseLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
        }
}
```

Я не понимаю. Например, в `applicationDidBecomeActive` у меня есть только этот код:`print ("applicationDidBecomeActive")`. И если я открываю центр управления или центр уведомлений и возвращаюсь в приложение во время отладки, я получаю это `applicationDidBecomeActive`, но моя анимация не останавливается. Но если я сверну приложение и вернусь или заблокирую iPhone и вернусь в приложение, я тоже получу это в отладке `applicationDidBecomeActive`, но в этом случае анимация останавливается. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Работающее решение с использованием `CABasicAnimation`, сделано на основе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471346/3004003) - запуск и возобновление анимации вращения с помощью кнопки или при сворачивании/разворачивании приложения

Расширение

```
extension UIView {
    
    /**
     Will rotate `self` for ever.
     
     - Parameter duration: The duration in seconds of a complete rotation (360º).
     - Parameter clockwise: If false, will rotate counter-clockwise.
     */
    func startRotating(duration: Double, clockwise: Bool) {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"
        var currentState = CGFloat(0)
        
        // Get current state
        if let presentationLayer = layer.presentation(),
           let zValue = presentationLayer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z") {
            currentState = CGFloat((zValue as AnyObject).floatValue)
        }
        
        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) == nil {
            let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            animate.duration = duration
            animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            animate.fromValue = currentState // Should the value be nil, will start from 0 a.k.a. "the beginning".
            animate.byValue = clockwise ? Float(.pi * 2.0) : -Float(.pi * 2.0)
            self.layer.add(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }
    
    /// Will stop a `startRotating(duration: _, clockwise: _)` instance.
    func stopRotating() {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"
        var currentState = CGFloat(0)
        
        // Get current state
        if let presentationLayer = layer.presentation(),
           let zValue = presentationLayer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z") {
            currentState = CGFloat((zValue as AnyObject).floatValue)
        }
        
        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) != nil {
            self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
        
        // Leave self as it was when stopped.
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(currentState, 0, 0, 1)
    }
    
}
```

Пример

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rotationButton: UIButton!
    var rotatingView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)),
            name:UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        
        setupUI()
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        
        rotationButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        rotationButton.setTitle("Start rotation", for: .normal)
        rotationButton.setTitle("Stop rotation", for: .selected)
        rotationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotationButtonTouchUpInside(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        rotationButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(rotationButton)
        rotationButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
        rotationButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        rotatingView = UIView()
        rotatingView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(rotatingView)
        rotatingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rotatingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        rotatingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        rotatingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        rotatingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
        print(#function)
        rotationButton.isSelected = true
        rotatingView.startRotating(duration: 3, clockwise: true)
    }
    
    @objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
        print(#function)
        rotationButton.isSelected = false
        rotatingView.stopRotating()
    }
    
    @objc func rotationButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected {
            rotatingView.stopRotating()
        } else {
            rotatingView.startRotating(duration: 3, clockwise: true)
        }
        
        sender.isSelected.toggle()
    }
    
    
}
```